# C++ using declaration

Tags: c++

Why does `using ::foo` declaration below hide all other `foo` functions?

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(double) { std::cout << "::foo(double)" << std::endl; }

struct A {
  void foo(float) { std::cout << "A::foo(float)" << std::endl; }
  void foo(int) { std::cout << "A::foo(int)" << std::endl; }
  void foo() { std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : A {
  using A::foo;
  void foo(int) { std::cout << "B::foo(int)" << std::endl; }
  void foo() { std::cout << "B::foo()" << std::endl; }

  void boo() {
    using ::foo;
    foo(1.0);
    foo(1.0f);
    foo(1);
    foo();
  };
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.boo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the same ADL lookup thing used for `std::swap` in copy-swap idiom. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782692/what-does-using-stdswap-inside-the-body-of-a-class-method-implementation-mea

Comment: ok, but why is B::foo() inaccessible?

Comment: @BlazBratanic It's not, have you tried `B::foo()`?

Comment: You are right. However, why do i need to explicitly specify which foo function? In this case the whole point of `using` declaration is lost since i could also call `::foo(1.0)`, `A::foo(1.0f)`, etc..

Comment: I think you need to also do `using B::foo;`

Comment: `using` is a *convenience*. When you have conflicts or need to specify scope, don't do it! And really, what is the point of `using ::foo;` other than to make `foo` be `::foo`?

Comment: @crashmstr: Might work for this case, but try that with enough templates, when you really want the compiler to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Any declaration of a function in an inner scope hides all declarations of functions with the same name in the outer scope.

You declared in the block scope of function boo function `::foo`

```
  void boo() {
    using ::foo;
    foo(1.0);
    foo(1.0f);
    foo(1);
    foo();
  };
```

It hides all functions with the same name in enclosing scopes.

More precisely. According to the C++ Standard

> 13 Since a using-declaration is a declaration, the restrictions on
>   declarations of the same name in the same declarative region (3.3)
>   also apply to using-declarations

Or maybe it would be better to cite the following quote from the C++ Standard

> 1 A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in
>   which the using-declaration appears.using-declaration:The member name
>   specified in a using-declaration is declared in the declarative region
>   in which the using-declaration appears.