# Use std::swap between vectors or vector::swap?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, swap

Given two std::vector v1, v2.
I was wondering what are the benefits to use std::swap(v1, v2) over v1.swap(v2).

I have implemented a simple test code (I am not sure it is pertinent) regarding performance point of view  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

#define N 100000

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::microseconds>
struct Timer
{
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename TimeT::rep exec(F func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<TimeT>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};

void test_std_swap(std::vector<double>& v1, std::vector<double>& v2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
    {
        std::swap(v1,v2);
        std::swap(v2,v1);
    }
}

void test_swap_vector(std::vector<double>& v1, std::vector<double>& v2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
    {
        v1.swap(v2);
        v2.swap(v1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> A(1000);
    std::generate( A.begin(), A.end(), [&]() { return std::rand(); } );
    std::vector<double> B(1000);
    std::generate( B.begin(), B.end(), [&]() { return std::rand(); } );
    std::cout << Timer<>::exec<void(std::vector<double>& v1, std::vector<double>& v2)>(test_std_swap, A, B) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Timer<>::exec<void(std::vector<double>& v1, std::vector<double>& v2)>(test_swap_vector, A, B)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << Timer<>::exec<void(std::vector<double>& v1, std::vector<double>& v2)>(test_std_swap, A, B) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Timer<>::exec<void(std::vector<double>& v1, std::vector<double>& v2)>(test_swap_vector, A, B)  << std::endl;
}
```

According to outputs it seems that vector::swap seems faster without optimization *-O0*.
Output is (in microseconds) :

```
20292
16246
16400
13898
```

And with *-O3* there is no revelant difference.

```
752
752
752
760
```

Comment: Other than generality.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes, absolutely. I meant "overloads" but now it is too late to edit my first comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should **not** use `std::swap()` directly in any case! Instead, you should use something like this:

```
using std::swap;
swap(x, y);
```

For `std::vector<...>` it probably doesn't make a difference as `std::vector<...>` obviously lives in namespace `std`. Otherwise the key difference is that with using `std::swap()` the default implementation is being used while with the approach outlined about ADL can find a better version.

Using `swap(x, y)` for `std::vector<...>`s `x` and `y` will just call `x.swap(y)`. For consistency with other uses I would use the approach listed above.

---

References:

- [How does "using std::swap" enable ADL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130671/how-does-using-stdswap-enable-adl?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [what does `using std::swap` inside the body of a class method implementation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782692/what-does-using-stdswap-inside-the-body-of-a-class-method-implementation-mea)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Is this a reason why std::swap seems slower without optimization with the above example ?

Comment: @coincoin: Profiling C++ code without optimizations is futile! For example, having function calls for everything trivially inlined adds a significant cost. Since production code surely always uses optimization the performance of unoptimized code is also irrelevant.

Comment: Downvoted because the actual answer to the question is only in the final paragraph, the rest is basically a comment on code style.  Also I disagree with the first part, I would say only use "using" if you really have to, in this case it's not necessary.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Your comment is simply not true, I do all my profiling on debug builds, I'm interested in optimising the algorithm being used, not removing a few function calls which make a trivial amount of difference.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming a sane implementation, both of those functions should be implemented identically. So you should use whatever is most readable in your code.

In particular, if we look at the description for `std::swap(vector<T> & x, vector<T> & y)`, it's effect is `x.swap(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

From implementation document:

```
void swap(vector& __x)

   *  This exchanges the elements between two vectors in constant time.
   *  (Three pointers, so it should be quite fast.)
   *  Note that the global std::swap() function is specialized such that
   *  std::swap(v1,v2) will feed to this function.
```

**You can see that, std::swap(v1,v2) just invoke v1.swap(v2).**