# c++: Swap first and second element for all tuples in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, tuples, swap

is there a way to swap the first and second elements for all tuples in a vector?
Let's say I have something like this:

```
#include<vector>
#include<tuple>

int main()
{
std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> my_vector;
my_vector.push_back(std::make_tuple(1,2));
my_vector.push_back(std::make_tuple(3,4));
}
```

The first elements of the tuple are now 1 and 3 with the second elements being 2 and 4. Is there an easy to make 2 and 4 the first elements?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: `std::tuple` can have more than two elements. Why don't you use `std::pair` instead?

Comment: So your question is actually: "How can I exchange the first and the second value of a 2 element tuple?"

Comment: *is there a way to swap the first and second elements for all tuples in a vector?* -- If the answer to that was "no", C++ would be a very weak language.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes this is basically my question. My english is not that great.

Comment: I think Jabberwocky just wanted to point out that it doesnt matter that the tuples are in a vector. If you know how to do it with one you also can do it in a loop with many

Comment: @AkariYukari -- *all tuples in a vector* -- Use `std::transform` and the appropriate lambda to swap.

Comment: Use `std::swap` and pass the result of `std::get<...>` for each value in the tuple?

Comment: Do you want to handle heterogeneous tuple, as `std::tuple<int,std::string>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) algorithm with a lambda:

```
std::for_each(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), [](auto& tuple) {
    std::swap(std::get<0>(tuple), std::get<1>(tuple));
});
```

You can also use a [range-based `for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto& tuple : my_vector)
    std::swap(std::get<0>(tuple), std::get<1>(tuple));
```

If you decide to replace `std::tuple` with `std::pair`, this code will also work, because `std::pair`'s members `first` and `second` [can be accessed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get) using `std::get<0>` and `std::get<1>`, respectively.

---

Instead of `std::swap(...)` you might want to write it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130671/how-does-using-stdswap-enable-adl):

```
using std::swap;
swap(std::get<0>(tuple), std::get<1>(tuple));
```

This is useful if instead of `int`, you have some user-defined type `T`, for which `void swap(T&, T&)` function is implemented (being presumably more performant than `std::swap`) and can be found by [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Answer (score 2):

Since your `std::tuple`s are containing only two values, I would suggest using `std::pair` instead.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> my_vector;
    my_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(1,2));
    my_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(3,4));

    for (auto const& p : my_vector) {
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto& p : my_vector) {
        std::swap(p.first, p.second);
    }

    for (auto const& p : my_vector) {
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:22,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:22,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::pair%3Cint,int%3E%3E+my_vector%3B%0A++++my_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(1,2))%3B%0A++++my_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(3,4))%3B%0A%0A++++for+(auto+const%26+p+:+my_vector)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+p.first+%3C%3C+%22+%22+%3C%3C+p.second+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++for+(auto%26+p+:+my_vector)+%7B%0A++++++++std::swap(p.first,+p.second)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++for+(auto+const%26+p+:+my_vector)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+p.first+%3C%3C+%22+%22+%3C%3C+p.second+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.308093994778076,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:45.97651026222455,l:'4',m:51.042810098792536,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:48.957189901207464,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.691906005221924,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 sure. I was planning to add that.