# A possible implementation of std::shuffle

Tags: c++, algorithm, shuffle, forwarding-reference

Here is an algorithm `std::shuffle` from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle:

> ```
>  template<class RandomIt, class URBG>
>  void shuffle(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, URBG&& g)
>  {
>      typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type diff_t;
>      typedef std::uniform_int_distribution<diff_t> distr_t;
>      typedef typename distr_t::param_type param_t;
>
>      distr_t D;
>      diff_t n = last - first;
>      for (diff_t i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
>          using std::swap;
>          swap(first[i], first[D(g, param_t(0, i))]);
>      }
>  }
> ```

- Why the algorithm takes a forwarding reference to the generator `URGB&& g`? As long as it didn't use `std::forward<URGB>(g)` to forward the generator either as an l-value or as an r-value?
- Why the using declaration is inside of loop body rather than outside of it? Does leaving it inside (iteratively) affects performance? Thank you!

Comment: because it's written by core staff. what's goal of this question? it's not a code for you to read

Answer (score 2):

> Why the algorithm takes a forwarding reference to the generator `URGB&&`
> `g`?

Because the algorithm does not want to copy the `generator`, it passes by *reference*, and in order to be able to accept the temporary rvalue `generator`, it takes a *forwarding reference*.

> As long as it didn't use `std::forward<URGB>(g)` to forward the
> generator either as an l-value or as an r-value?

Because the `generator` is not only invoked *once*. If the rvalue is forwarded, its state may be changed before the next invoked.

> Why the using declaration is inside of loop body rather than outside
> of it?

This is a so-called [`std::swap` two-step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130671/how-does-using-stdswap-enable-adl), and it is idiomatic to use unqualified `swap` immediately after `using std::swap`. The advantage of putting it inside the loop is that its scope is limited to the loop, and putting it outside may pollute the naming.

> Does leaving it inside (iteratively) affects performance?

No.

Comment: Wht you mean with "`std::swap` two step"? so do you mean: `using std::swap; for(;;){  swap(x, y);}` aren't the same as `for(;;){ using std::swap; swap(x, y);}`?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa. They are the same. But the latter is an idiom form.

Comment: Would you tell me about the latter? I've not heard about it.

Comment: I know this although I don't know its name "two-steps swap" but you didn't get my point. I said: why not using 'two-steps swap' in a way putting the using declaration  outside of the loop body: `using std::swap; for(){ swap(x, y);}` rather than inside loop body: `for(){ using std::swap; swap(x, y);}`

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa. As I said, this is just idiomatic style. You can also put it on the outside. The advantage of putting it inside the for-loop is that its scope is only inside the for-loop, and putting it outside the for loop [may pollute the naming](https://godbolt.org/z/Pcd1zTa1K).

Comment: This usage of `&&` I think is called a universal reference (as opposed to a forwarding reference, even though to the compiler they are the same thing) and it means that if you call the function passing an l-value generator the generator will be called as an l-value, but if you call it with an r-value then the generator will only be called as an r-value

Comment: @SirGuy. The current C++ standard term is [forwarding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552272/is-there-a-difference-between-universal-references-and-forwarding-references).