# How to pass a generic function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I am writing a program that calculates the time it takes to sort a vector.
There's multiple sorters and I want to be able to call them all from the same function. 
Here's on of the sorter itself.
 Please note that the sorter has to be generic.

**SelectionSort.h**

```
template <typename T>
void selectionSort(T& v){
   if(!v.empty()){
      size_t iMin;
      for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i){
         iMin = i;
         for(size_t j = i + 1; j < v.size();++j){
            if (v[j] < v[iMin])
               iMin = j;
         }
         std::swap(v[i], v[iMin]);
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the part where I calculate the time it takes to sort.
 In that case I want it to be a vector of int.

**timeCalculation.cpp**

```
typedef std::vector<int> V;
template <typename Fn>
   std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>
   mesureTemps(Fn f,V &v1, unsigned iter) {
      std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> tempsTot{};
      for(unsigned i = 0; i < iter; ++i) {
         std::shuffle(v1.begin(),v1.end(),std::rand());
         auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
         f(v1);
         auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
         tempsTot += (t2 - t1);
      }
   return tempsTot /= iter;
}
int main() {
   std::vector<int> v(N);
   std::iota(v.begin(),v.end(),1);
   auto tempsMoyen = mesureTemps(selectionSort, v,
      10);
   std::cout << tempsMoyen.count();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I cannot find a way to call mesureTemps without breaking at compilation.

Comment: Don't use `high_resolution_clock` for timing, it's not guaranteed to be monotonic. Use `steady_clock` instead.

Comment: `selectionSort` in the context you're using it in `main` is broken because you never tell it the type of container it's using. `selectionSort<V>` *should* work in that context, though I'm gonna be honest with you, this is much easier with iterators all-around rather than pumping your container type down the template argument chute. Anyway, that `std::rand()` is clearly wrong as well.

Comment: Offtopic but important: don't call `std::swap` directly, use `using std::swap; swap(v[i], v[iMin]);` instead.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Why is that important?  I've not seen it done elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulSanders https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130671/how-does-using-stdswap-enable-adl

Comment: `mesureTemps(selectionSort<decltype(v)>, v, 10);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this creates another problem at compilation , ```error: 'std::remove_reference<int>::type' {aka 'int'} is not a class, struct, or union type```

Comment: `std::shuffle(v1.begin(),v1.end(),std::rand())` call is wrong. You are passing an `int` where a [*UniformRandomBitGenerator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator) object is expected.