# overloading std::to_string and std::to_chars for a custom type?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I have an arithmetic custom type with a `to_string()` member. I'm thinking about overloading `std::to_string` in the `std` namespace for the type, but would this count as namespace pollution?

EDIT:
I'm thinking about this, so that this expression SFINAE would work for the type:
`-> decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()), void(0))`

Comment: [This extending the `std` namespace reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) could be useful. In short, overloading e.g. `std::to_string` is not allowed (and leads to UB).

Comment: An alternative could be to keep `to_string` and `to_chars` in your own namespace, and than [leverage argument dependent lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4782692/2486888). But it may be tricky.

Comment: Could we see your full proposal? (interested)

Comment: I'll just experiment with ADL, hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 3):

As [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220491/overloading-stdto-string-and-stdto-chars-for-a-custom-type#comment89421797_51220491), you cannot add declarations into `std` namespace in this case.

Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562/5376789), a workaround is to write your `to_string` in the same namespace as your custom class, and use `using std::to_string` to bring `std::to_string` in overload resolution when you want to use `to_string` for generic type. The following is an example:

```
#include <string>

struct A {};

std::string to_string(A) {return "";}

namespace detail { // does not expose "using std::to_string"
    using std::to_string;
    template <typename T>
    decltype(to_string(std::declval<T>()), void(0)) foo() {}
}
using detail::foo;

int main()
{
    foo<int>();      // ok
    foo<A>();        // ok
    // to_string(0); // error, std::to_string is not exposed
}
```