# What's the difference between std::ranges::swap() and std::swap()?

Tags: c++, stl, standards, c++20, std-ranges

In C++20, there are two `swap` function templates: [`std::ranges::swap(T&&, U&&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/ranges/swap) and [`std::swap(T&, T&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

I just wonder:

**What's the difference between they two?**

Comment: Since you link to cppreference: what is unclear in those pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rough terms: `std::ranges::swap` generalizes `std::swap`.

- If `T` and `U` are the same, then it's equivalent to invoking `std::swap`.
- Otherwise it will swap the arguments as two ranges - if they're ranges.
- Otherwise it will perform a swap-like procedure with move assignment between the different types T and U.
- If even that can't happen, it will fail to compile.

See the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/ranges/swap) for details.

I must say I find this function to be somewhat confusing and baroque, but then - maybe people more experienced with the range library develop an intuition as to why it makes sense.

Comment: "_baroque_" is worth an upvote in itself (although it sneeks an opinion in there).

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I said it was my personal impression ("I find").

Comment: Yes, and I think that it's important that relatively new additions to the library or language is questioned - even here at SO where opinions like this tend to not age well.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Well, you might enjoy my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39382501/1593077) then - especially in light of the accepted answer.

Comment: That's also an Interesting and important view. I did not find it compelling enough for an upvote right now but I will re-read it later.

Answer (score 8):

`std::swap` has a problem. It's possible that there is a more efficient swap function that is not in the `std` namespace. You should enable ADL to find and use that if available and use `std::swap` otherwise. It's called "std 2-step":

```
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

But `std::ranges::swap` doesn't have this problem and will call the version ADL would have called:

```
std::ranges::swap(a, b);
```

[Here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5zMnPxY1j) is a demonstration.

Comment: "It's possible that there is a more efficient swap function that is not in the std namespace" <- Isn't that theoretically true for a huge number of std namespace functions?

Comment: Can we safely say: `std::swap` should be totally replaced with `std::ranges::swap`?

Comment: @xmllmx yes. You should use `std::ranges::swap` in all new code.

Comment: @einpoklum `swap` is very often overloaded for custom classes unlike much of the rest of the standard library. If everyone starts using the ranges version, we don't have to keep teaching folks to always remember to enable ADL before using `swap` in particular. Additionally, ranges also include `begin`, `end`, etc which also previously required ADL to work with custom types at all.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili:  1. Teaching people to not use `std::swap()` when they want to swap is not that different then having them incant the "magic spell" of `using std::swap`. 3. If this is relevant for `std::swap`, why not `std::sort`, and all sorts of algorithms too?

Comment: @einpoklum The problem is that `std::swap` is very often overloaded while I've never seen `std::sort` overloaded. This is a very common idiom if you google "std 2-step". This one for instance: [what does `using std::swap` inside the body of a class method implementation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4782809/10147399).